# Elasticsearh error:No alive nodes found in the cluster

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I am new at elastic search and have very little knowledge about it. I have integrated elasticsearch with laravel 5.4. The serch was working fine in my localhost but after uploading the project to the server(Shared Hosting) it was  giving me the following error

> NoNodesAvailableException in StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php line 51:
>   No alive nodes found in your cluster

After I reconfigured the .env file like this

```
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX=scout
ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=http://localhost
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9300
```

it worked fine. But don't know why later it didn't worked and gave me the same error. I know this might sound ridiculous but someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the Elasticsearch search server is available on localhost:9300 when accessing it via curl/Postman/Fiddler?

That error usually means the node is either not running, or not running on the configured port.

Comment: 9300 is a port for TCP communications, so curl/Postman et al won't work there. 9200 is the port to use in order to communicate via HTTP with ES.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use port 9200 for HTTP communication. 9300 is for TCP communication. That's most probably the only issue.

```
ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX=scout
ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=http://localhost
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200                <-- change this line
```